# How to debug mouse going crazy on Thinkpad T14s

Tags: xfce, manjaro, mouse, thinkpad

I have an unusual issue recently with Thinkpad T14s. My trackpad is disabled in BIOS, I use the trackpoint. Randomly the mouse will suddenly go completely crazy, jumping around and opening menus / moving windows around / closing windows. It seems like the mouse buttons are randomly being triggered somehow.

If I close and open the laptop lid, it works again. Also, an external usb mouse works fine.

I've had some other odd issues like the keyboard not working or mouse click events not triggering too, and would like to debug it but don't know where to start.